# Message Boxes not showed

Tags: vb.net

net Programmers
I am in a trouble 
I want to display messagebox after a while of time
i did this but the problem is that the messagebox appears behind the other windows of the active programs 
I want a code that displays the messagebox over all opened windows to make the user see it
and THANKS

Comment: Use one of the overloads of MessageBox.Show that takes an owner as a parameter.  Pass in your form as the owner.  Then the message box should appear on top of your form.

Answer (score 2):

You can't set TopMost on a message box.  However, you could create your own class/dialog set TopMost to true on it and then use ShowDialog to display it.